# Dynamic SQL with out parameters

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to convert a normal STP to a partially dynamic SQL
I need the dynamic part to set value to a parameter, which I would later use in my non-dynamic part of the STP.

when I print it in the inside of the dynamic @stmt it's OK but outside it is empty

what am  I missing?

--------------------------------------------------------------constructing statement

```
set @stmt = 'set @stringActors = cast((select actors.actor_id
    '+@from_clause+' '
    +@where_clause+' '
    +'for xml raw,type) as varchar(max)) print @stringActors'

print @stmt
```

--------------------------------------------------------------execution

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt,N'
@stringActors varchar(4000) output
,@user_actor bigint
,@internal_search_actor varchar(30)
,@internal_search_route_manager     varchar(30)
,@internal_search_terminal_id       varchar(30)
,@ACTOR_TYPE_INSTITUTE int 
,@ACTOR_TYPE_LOCATION int'
,@stringActors =@stringActors
,@user_actor=@user_actor
,@internal_search_actor=@internal_search_actor
,@internal_search_route_manager=@internal_search_route_manager
,@internal_search_terminal_id=@internal_search_terminal_id
,@ACTOR_TYPE_INSTITUTE=@ACTOR_TYPE_INSTITUTE
,@ACTOR_TYPE_LOCATION=@ACTOR_TYPE_LOCATION
```

-----------------------------------------------------------------rest of STP (not dynamic)
print @stringActors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OUTPUT has to be specified both when declaring and assigning an OUTPUT parameter, so I would say the problem is

```
,@stringActors =@stringActors
,@user_actor=@user_actor
```

should be

```
,@stringActors =@stringActors OUTPUT
,@user_actor=@user_actor
```

Also, check out this [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499)

Comment: This has bit me in the behind a few times, but once you get that experience under your belt, you never forget it.  Also, a tip from someone who writes a LOT of dynamic-SQL: prefix your "inner" parameters with something like "@pActors" or "iActors", because it makes it easier to read and write the param-setter clause of the sp_executesql command.  Like so: `EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt, N'
@pStringActors varchar(4000) output', @pStringActors = @stringActors OUTPUT`